# RxJS - Observable.map generate objects with asynchronous initilatization

Tags: asynchronous, rxjs

```
return this.http.get(url)
.map((response:Response) => {
  return (<any>response.json()).map(actu => new Actualite(actu));      
});
```

From this example.
The 'Actualite' constructor generate the value of one of its properties asynchronously (load image from url and manipulate it to a canvas)

```
export class Actualite {
Credit: string;
Mini: string;
/* ... */


constructor(fichier:any) {
    this.Credit =       fichier.Credit || '';
    this.Mini =         fichier.Mini || '';
    /* ... */


    if(this.Mini) {
        let img:HTMLImageElement = new Image();
        img.src = this.Mini;

        img.addEventListener('load', ()=> {

            let canvas:HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            let ctx:CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext('2d');

            /*....... Image transformation......*/

            this.Data = canvas.toDataURL();


        })
    }
}
```

}

So I want to subscribe this Observable first code when the asynchronous objects initialization is over and not, as in this example, when the objects are created

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a reference to an observable created from the load event of the image in the `actualite` class.

Something like

```
constructor(fichier:any) {
    /*...*/
    this.loadObservable = Rx.Observable.empty() // case where `Mini` is false
    // you can also return a Rx.Observable.of(defaultValue) if you need something on the other side

    if (this.Mini) {
        let img:HTMLImageElement = new Image();
        img.src = this.Mini;

        this.loadObservable = Rx.Observable
          .fromEvent(img, "load")
          .map(event => /*... do you stuff with the image ...*/)
    }
}
```

Now you can use this observable from the outside

```
return this.http.get(url)
  .map((response:Response) => {
    return (<any>response.json())
      .map(actu => new Actualite(actu))
      .mergeMap(actu => actu.loadObservable); // this will emit when the loadObservable emits   
  });
```